# TV connected via HDMI for audio only?

Tags: windows, audio, display, video, hdmi

Samsung TV has better speakers than my laptop. I want to have audio going through the TV without extra load on my video card. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Does your TV not also have separate audio inputs (say [RCA-style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector))? Does your notebook have a headphone jack?

Comment: It does and that's what I'll be using in a couple weeks I suppose. I'm at a labour camp right now though in the middle of nowhere with just a HDMI cable.

Comment: This will work just fine if you tweak with the settings. I use Catalyst Control Center and i know that it has the option to do this.

Comment: Alright so what I have up here is a Samsung LN22B360C5D. It has PC VGA and 3.5mm input, DVI/HDMI with RCA audio input, AV in for composite RCA (3-pin), and component in for component RCA (5-pin). I've hooked up the HDMI just to get a signal, hooked up the stereo RCA cables from my headphone output on the laptop to the audio RCAs for HDMI/DVI on the TV, disabled the digital audio via nVidia CP, Speakers are default device in sound properties (not digital), but there's no sound. I've also tried a composite cable with the proper source and inputs on the back of the tv, no luck there either.

Comment: Headphones work fine when plugged into the headphone output on my laptop while the TV is connected VIA HDMI, so the headphone output works. I also have a male-to-male 3.5mm cable but I can't test it without the TV getting a signal on the VGA port.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the HDMI standard insists there must be some picture, even if it's just black screen.

If that would be OK, then maybe some type of HDMI breakout box to separate the audio - something like this http://www.amazon.co.uk/Av-Tool-HDMI-AUDIO-BREAKOUT/dp/B00BBE77H8

I've never tested it, so I've no idea how it would work.